# Visual Studio 2010 Local Machine-Project Specific Properties

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, properties

I am using VC++ with multiple projects that require a 3rd party library. As developers may have this library in different paths, each developer sets the local machine/user's Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user property sheet with the appropriate paths.

Now we using a new version of the 3rd party library with some of the projects. As before, different developers may have the new library in different paths. How do we set local **machine and project** specific paths so that we can compile both old and new library projects?

Modifying a project's 'VC++ Directories' changes the project file (.vcxproj) which then poses a problem as we do not want to commit local settings into the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We normally set an environment variable for each library that can be set by each developer in their environment in a env.bat file they run before running devenv (some made up examples) :-

```
ZLIB_ROOT=c:\somewhere\thirdparty\zlib
BOOST_ROOT=c:\somewhere\thirdparty\boost\version_123
```

and then in the project files add directories use "$(ZLIB_ROOT)/Include" or "$(ZLIB_ROOT)/Lib/x86" (all made up examples again...)

That way they will resolve correctly for any developer and they can have a different env.bat script for each version